# Range for selecting 1 cell up excel powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm attempting to automate creation of charts with data from excel. Am able to select a range by using range.end. However, the range I need is selection till end -1 and I have no idea how to do make that happen. Any advise please?

Here is a snippet of my simple code:

```
$xl = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$xldirection = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XLDirection]

$wb = $xl.workbooks.open($filename)
$wsData = $wb.worksheets.item(1)
$wsdata.activate()

$start = $wsData.Range("E25")
$data = $wsData.Range($start, $start.End($xldirection::xldown))

$wschart = $wb.sheets.add();
$chart = $wschart.shapes.addchart().chart
$chart.setSourceData($data)
```

Comment: `$start = $ws.Data...` - `$ws` is not defined anywhere else. Typo? Should it be `$wb` or `$wsData`?

Comment: I dont have a variable named $ws. Only $wsData. But I see the issue. Edited that line as its a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, you are still working with Excel ranges. You should have a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range?view=excel-pia) to understand this type of object more.

On there, you will see that you can access the `Row` and `Column` properties of a range object. Then you can just do "Row - 1" to get second to last row.

```
$xl = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$xldirection = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XLDirection]

$wb = $xl.workbooks.open($filename)
$wsData = $wb.worksheets.item(1)
$wsdata.activate()

$start = $wsData.Range("E25")
$end   = "E" + ($start.End($xldirection::xldown).row - 1) # new line
$data = $wsData.Range($start, $end)                       # amended line

$wschart = $wb.sheets.add();
$chart = $wschart.shapes.addchart().chart
$chart.setSourceData($data)
```

Comment: gms0ulman, thanks for this. I do see the documentation but am not able to find the correct syntax. Would read up more on it.